# Send JSONObject from android app to node.js over http?

Tags: android, json, node.js

Im having issues finding tutorial for this subject. Do anyone have an good example. 
I want to send an JSONObject from a android app over http to node.js. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. OK, start by [learning about HTTP & REST](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/) to decide whether you want to PUT or POST your JSON.
2. Create a HTTPRequest in your Android app that puts the JSON into the HTTP message's body. See:

   - [How to send POST request in JSON using HTTPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http)
   - [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Back to node:

3. Set up a node.js http handler for that type of request. I recommend using [express](http://expressjs.com/), since it's easy and you'll find the most examples & support when using it.
4. Use a body parser in express to [read the JSON object](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body).
5. $$$ PROFIT $$$