# Android http post advanced request with body on hostmachine

Tags: java, android, http-post

I would like to do a HTTP post request from my virtual android device on the hostmachine.
Below you'll see an image on how I post, by using the old WebFetch tool.

1. I don't know what URL to use for calling the hostmachine?
2. I got no idea how my body string can be used an input?

[image]

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: a) please post source code b) why is the link you have blocked as porn.illicit?

Comment: @azulflame: I've removed his link and added its referenced image.

Comment: @josh thanks. I was at school, and the lightspeed filter blocked the site as "porn.illict"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Also check out the accepted answer in following question to see how json can be send as post data:

[How to send POST request in JSON using HTTPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http)

you can use following code to make HTTP get request:

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String getURL = "http://10.0.2.2:port/your_path_with_parameter";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
        if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                    //do something with the response
                    Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wasn't able to try anything, because I simply miss the experience here. The only thing I'm really sure of, is that my Webfetch is posting and provides the objects. Do you possibly have a code snippet?

Comment: please explain what are you trying to do? Do you need to make http get request or http post request? are you getting json in the response?

Comment: My goal is to put some input parameters inside and send it to the servicebus, and receive an object containing all results. I guess it's json which I get back.

Comment: Can I simply put my body text, which you can see in the webfetch screenshot, in a string inclusive curly brackets?

Comment: please check link in my answer for making post request with json data.. posting it again.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http