# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp and JSON POST ARRAY

Tags: android, json, http, post, android-async-http

I was using LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp library to comunicate with my PhP Server. And i got a problem.

I need to send a JsonObject like that:

```
{      "data": 2376845,      
       "data2": 12545,      
       "array": [{"data3": "2013-01-10",          
                     "data4": 23532        },       
                    {"data3": "2013-01-11",             
                     "data4": 523526   }]
}
```

But in the javadoc; the only parameters it's RequestParams, and don't have any kind of Array.
Can AnyOne Help me? Or Show me something that i can use.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use

```
public void post(Context context, String url, HttpEntity entity, String contentType, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
```

instead of:

```
public void post(Context context, String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
```

Parse your JSON as a String:

```
ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(bodyAsJson.getBytes("UTF-8"));
client.post(context, newUrl, entity, "application/json", responseHandler);
```

Where client is an AsyncHttpClient and bodyAsJson is a JSON inside a String

```
yourJsonObj.toString()
```

Comment: AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));


client.post(getApplicationContext(), URL_connect,entity, "application/json",  new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

And I get null on the server, why?

Comment: And That's how i create the Json Structure:

JSONObject m1 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject m2 = new JSONObject();       
 List  l1 = new LinkedList();       
 m1.put("data1","2013-01-10");
 m1.put("data2","234652");        
 m2.put("data1","2013-01-11");
 m2.put("data2","234235");        
  l1.add(m1);
  l1.add(m2);        
 jsonObject.put("data3", l1);
        jsonObject.put("data4", string1);
        jsonObject.put("data5", string2);

Comment: Mm its difficult reading that here, can you debug it?
Logcat should tell you in which line and class is the Null Pointer Exception generating.

Comment: Cannot pass boolean by this method. Boolean gets converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

We can build the Above json format using JsonObject class which is available with javax.json-1.0.2.jar,

```
JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("data", 2376845)
            .add("data2", 12545)
            .add("array",Json.createArrayBuilder()
                    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("data3", "2013-01-10").add("data4", 23532).build())
                    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("data3", "2013-01-11").add("data4", 523526).build()))
                    .build();
```

After building json format

```
        AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        Request request = client.preparePost(your host URL).
        setHeader("Content-Type","application/json").
        setHeader("Content-Length", ""+jo.toString().length()).setHeader("Authorization","Basic fgfgfgfhfhtetet=").
        setBody(jo.toString()).build();
        ListenableFuture<Response> r = null;
        //ListenableFuture<Integer> f= null;
        try{
        r = client.executeRequest(request);
        System.out.println(r.get().getResponseBody());
        }catch(IOException e){

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

if you required basic authentication you need to add a key which is combination of username:password encoded with base64 to header,if not leave it 
in this case i added it to header

mostly this will work's for you

Note:AsyncHttpClient,ListenableFuture classes are available in async-http-client-1.7.5.jar