# How to use post method in android using json

Tags: java, android, json

I have created an android apps using json for getting from ror website and displaying in listview,Right now i want to add the data from our apps,it has to display in listview in our apps also and then it has to show in website also.How to use post method and display in our apps.

to get method i used like that

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);   
        initView();
    }

    private void initView()
    {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

fetchdatatask.java

```
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private final FetchDataListener listener;
    private String msg;

    public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        if ( params == null )
            return null;
        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];
        try
        {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if ( entity == null )
            {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }
            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            msg = "No Network Connection";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson)
    {
        if ( sJson == null )
        {
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // convert json string to json object
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sJson);
            JSONArray aJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");
            // create apps list
            List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();
            for ( int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Application app = new Application();
                app.setContent(json.getString("content"));
                // add the app to apps list
                apps.add(app);
            }
            //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
        }
        catch ( JSONException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Invalid response";
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * 
     * @param is
     *            respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Like this i am using get method and displaying also,for same purpose i want to add the post method to displaying in android listview and shown in website also.

**if i will create one button if i click the menu button like add,in that one it will shows one page,in that page i have to add the data and click save,it has to display in listview and post in website also**

How i can do that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpPost

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    if ( params == null )
        return null;
    // get url from params
    String url = params[0];
    try
    {
        // create http connection
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        try{
    StringEntity s = new StringEntity(json.toString()); //json is ur json object
    s.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
    s.setContentType("application/json");
    request.setEntity(s);
    request.addHeader("Accept", "text/plain"); //give here your post method return type

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        // get response
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if ( entity == null )
        {
            msg = "No response from server";
            return null;
        }
        // get response content and convert it to json string
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        return streamToString(is);
```

Comment: This is code for sending data to server, you have to write post method at your server which can accept json object.

Comment: actually if i will give the menu click button in that button one add popup will opens ,if i click means it shows new activity which has one edittexbox and save,from their how to fetch it for server and how we can make to display in listview,where we can save in server or db

Comment: write a click event on save button to fetch the data from edittext. you can retrieve data from edittext using myeditText.getText().toString(); myeditText is your edittext name. Convert this data to json object and call your asynchronus task

Comment: can u see that link,can i use that one in my code,how to fetch that string and post it

Comment: for me one doubt,how to fetch the data and display in lisview,and convert that data to json object @Ashu

Comment: actually i am not getting correctly from your side,i am very confussed

Comment: are you there ,do u have gtalk@Ashu,i am very confused how to do that one

Comment: For converting data to json object you can import json jar file. You will get a built in class JSONObject. you can use it like this. JSONObject json=new JSONObject(); json.put("key","value");

Comment: i have lots of things,wants to discuss,could you give your gtalk,i am very confusing that how to start that work@Ashu

Comment: my gtalk karthickbe2008@gmail.com,here you can guide me how to do pls,i am very struck in that function

Comment: I have sent you an invitation, mine is kumar.asutosh49@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The main steps you have to take are these:

**Add code in your Android app to post the data to your server.**
You can find lots of examples on how to do this online. Here's one example:
[How to send POST request in JSON using HTTPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http)

**Have a web service that can tace care of the JSON data you send.**
How to do this depends on what server side thechnology you're using.

**Update the List that is tied to your ListView**

Comment: ,is this i want to do in server side also