# Sending JSON object to Rails app

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I’m somewhat new to `Android`, `JSON`, and `Rails` so please forgive my ignorance or if I’m too vague. I’ve built a basic Android app that builds a `JSON` object with red, green, and blue values. I’ve also built a `Ruby` site with a `Model` for “Settings” that creates a new entry with red, green, and blue value. I can create the new entries using “**mysite.com/settings/new**”, entering my values, and then hitting “Create” (I’m using pretty much the default rails stuff and used rails generate scaffold). The problem I’m having is building the “bridge” between the two technologies.  What path do I send this data to?  I’ve read this post: [How to send POST request in JSON using HTTPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http)  as reference but I’m unsure what “path” to pass to the HttpPost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is `mysite.com/settings`.

This path will map to `SettingsController#create` if you send a POST request to it, and will map to `SettingsController#index` if sending a GET request.

You can run `$rake routes` in command line within your Rails app. Then you'll see list of all routes.

Make sure your request is POST and content-type is JSON as the other question you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What i would for for a project like this is create a API take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem

then you can tell your Android app to get the data from there.