# How to store all data in single array so that I can easily post it as request?

Tags: android, json, post, multidimensional-array, httprequest

I am trying to create nested jsonArray so that I can post this to server.

I want to post this type of json to server:

```
{
"topnode": {
    "node1": {
        "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
       
    },
    "node2": {
        "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
    },
    "node3": {
        "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
    },
    "node4": {
        "node4_1": [
            {
                "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "2", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "3", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ],
        "Node4_2": [
            {
                 "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "2", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ],
        "Node4_3": [
            {
                "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",  
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Node5": {
        "A": [
            {
                 "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "2", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "3", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ],
        "B": [
            {
                 "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                 "id": "2", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ],
        "C": [
            {
                 "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "2", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ],
        "D": [
            {
                 "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            },
            {
               "id": "1", 
        "SecurityQuestion": "1",
        "SecuirtyAnswer": "11",
        "CreatedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "ModifiedDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59",
        "AuthDate": "2015-03-16 11:30:59"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I am not getting any idea how to do this. Here is what I am trying:

```
        JSONArray obj_tArray = new JSONArray();
                additionalArrayData  = new JSONArray();
             for (salary tSalary : tsalary_arrayOfList) { 
                 
                    additionalData.put("employer", tSalary .getemployer());
                    additionalData.put("name", tSalary .getname());
                    additionalData.put("income_head_salary", tSalary .getincome_head_salary());
                    additionalData.put("total", tSalary .gettotal());
                    additionalData.put("year", tSalary .getYear());
                    additionalData.put("panCardNumber", tSalary .getUserPanCard());
                    additionalData.put("income_head_salary", tSalary .getincome_head_salary());
                                        
                    obj_tArray.put(additionalData); 
                } 
         
            additionalArrayData.put("t_salary"); 
            additionalArrayData.put(1, obj_TArray);
```

Comment: where did u got so far?

Comment: m trying like this @eduyayo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/how-to-send-post-request-in-json-using-httpclient

Comment: i am able to create request but dont no how to put all this node in a single array. :( @eduyayo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject middleObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();

innerObject.put("id", "1");
innerObject.put("SecurityQuestion", "TestQuestion");

middleObject.put("node1", innerObject);
outerObject.put("topnode", middleObject);
```

This is how you get nested JSONObjects. You need to add your logic for iterating over the different objects now.

Comment: Thank you for providing me path @Deutro