# How to make the content-type: application/json in the apache httpPost method

Tags: java, json, content-type, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using the below code and it is showing the Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but I want this code to be Content-Type: application/json.
Please suggest what changes needed to this code to make it an application/json request.

```
  private String baseUrl = "myIPAddress";
    private HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(baseUrl + "app/registration");
            try {
                String line = "";
                for (int rIndex = 0; rIndex < goodAuthenticationPairs.length; rIndex++) {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","myEmail@test.com"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","myPassword"));
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    //post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    System.out.println(post);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    line = rd.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(line);
                    String actualResult = json.get("return_code").toString();

                    assertTrue("0".equals(actualResult));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
```

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6218563/4720017

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the content type inside header of the request....

```
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

you can also see the same discussion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/how-to-send-post-request-in-json-using-httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

I think uncommenting the line

```
//post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: Yea I already tried that, thats why it is commented there

Answer (score -2):

This may serve the need ..

`response.setContentType("application/json");`

Comment: Nopes that will also not help. As we want to change the content-Type of request.