# How to use docker remote api to create container In java?

Tags: java, docker

I want to using docker remote api in [this](http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/).
I have succeed in this command to create container:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Image": " registry:2",}' http://192.168.59.103:2375/containers/create?name=test_remote_reg
```

Then,I use HttpClient(4.3.1) in java to try to create container via this code:

```
    String containerName = "test_remote_reg";
    String imageName = "registry:2";
    String url = DockerConfig.getValue("baseURL")+"/containers/create?name="+containerName;
    List<NameValuePair> ls = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    ls.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Image",imageName));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity fromEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(ls, "uTF-8");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", " application/json");
    if(null!=fromEntity) post.setEntity(fromEntity);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.execute(post);
```

It didn't work, and throw error:

```
invalid character 'I' looking for beginning of value
```

I just add header information and add param pair about "Image:test_remote_reg".
What is wrong about my java code? What difference is between they? What should I edit for my java code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering this is a json call, you could use one of the answers of [HTTP POST using JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25821756/6309), like (replace the JSON part by your JSON parameters):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://yoururl");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity("details={\"name\":\"myname\",\"age\":\"20\"} ");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    // handle response here...
}catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Comment: You have other options at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27057519/6309. In your case, the `StringEntity` would be `StringEntity("{\"Image\":" + imageName + "}")`

Comment: Wow, so cool for your answer. I have understood what is wrong about my code. It is json parameters, But I just use NameValuePair. Thanks a lot!