# Malformed UTF-8 when sending JSON from android to WAMP server

Tags: java, php, android, json, gson

I've been looking around the web for a way to send JSON to my server and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/how-to-send-post-request-in-json-using-httpclient/11921827#11921827) really helpful answer. I used that to send JSON to my server and the plan was then to decode it, however for some reason I can't seem to be able to get it right.

I use GSON to encode a `HashMap` into a JSON string

```
Map<String, String> myData = new HashMap<String, String>();
myData.put("count", "1");
myData.put("id", "1000");
myData.put("name", "Äpple");
String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(myData, Map.class);
```

With the JSON string I send it to my server using `HttpPost`.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Brilliant, now I only have to receive the encoded JSON on my WAMP server and use the *awesome* builtin JSON functionality of php to decode it.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) {
    $json = str_replace(chr($i), "", $json);
}
$json = str_replace(chr(127), "", $json);

if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($json), 'efbbbf')) {
    $json = substr($json, 3);
}
$json = stripslashes($json);

$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

As it turns out the builtin JSON support perhaps isn't so awesome after all. Maybe it has something to do with the PHP version I am using (`5.5.12`)?

Here is the JSON data I am trying so desperately to decode with php:

```
{"count":"1","id":"1000","name":"Äpple"}
```

If that isn't enough here is the hex dump of the `$json` variable (after removing the "hidden characters" in my string):

```
7b22636f756e74223a2231222c226964223a2231303030222c226e616d65223a22c470706c65227d
```

The examples gives me "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" from `json_last_error()`.

Will someone be so kind to explain why and how I send properly encoded UTF-8 characters?

Comment: is this a typo: `$data = json_decode(json, true);` ? (missing `$`)

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Yup, sorry that was stupid. It now gives me another error "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded". I'm going to update my question.

Comment: works for me https://ideone.com/3bxcnL

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ the thing is it is parsed directly from `php://input` which is sent from android. My belief is that android uses some other encoding than UTF-8 thus php will give an error. Perhaps looking at the hex dump will tell something useful.

Comment: try this: `httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));` and this: `setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`; it is generally a good idea to do so. Anyway I'd say Android jvm is definitely using utf-8 charset. Your IDE maybe not, if the value is hardcoded.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Thanks a lot! It almost works. Although when I insert the json element `name` to a mysql database it seems malformed. The result is `Ã„pple` which is not identical to `Äpple`. Any ideas?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Nevermind I think I got it working. I needed to setup mysql to use utf8 aswell. I added `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` before inserting the value into the database. Thank you for your help!