# Http post android with json

Tags: android, json, http, http-post

I want to allow people to register via my application by sending data in my database on the internet. They have to fill (last name, first name, email, phone, city, school, business and opinion). 
How should I proceed to enable registering with post Http android, and post data with json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6218563/2235972

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet when read I don't understand where have I to put this contents (last name, first name, email etc ). Somebody can give me an example ? I'm a beginner

Comment: @HenriG Since you are a beginner, I would suggest you to follow a tutorial that does exactly that and also read up documentations and stuff. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fmcmxbDLhg

Comment: Ok @RafiduzzamanSonnet I'll try and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

It actually pretty straight forward, grab this github repo https://github.com/chrisberry/WebAPIWithAndroidUI it should give you the basics

Comment: I don't understand the content @thechrisberry. Please give me an example ? where have I to put my url where I stock online datas ?