# Send the data of edittextfield from android to node.js

Tags: javascript, android, json, node.js, mongodb

My backendcode i.e node.js is running fine i have checked it by sending some data in json format using postman and they are getting stored in my db(mongodb) and now i want to take the data from edittextfield android and send it to the server.the code that i have written is hitting the server but i am not getting the data. i have checked in console.log(req)  it is not contaning the data that i am sending.
And i have seen previous posts that were asked related to this but it didnt helped me

here is the android code

```
          private static String url_create_product =   
                                   "http://192.168.1.3:3000/contactlist"; 

          protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


            Log.d("params",params.toString());

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);


            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                     MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);


                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
```

here is the node.js code

```
       app.post('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
         console.log("i am going to insert");
        console.log(req);
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.query);
        console.log(req.params);

          db.users.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
                                          res.json(doc);
               console.log(doc)
           });
      });
```

here is the error
        [the errors that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCZ1f.png)

the makehttprequest method code is 
         public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params) {

```
    try {// check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
     try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

server error

```
    Error: invalid json
    at parse (E:\app10 - Copy\node_modules\body-     parser\lib\types\json.js:79:15)
     at E:\app10 - Copy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:102:18
at done (E:\app10 - Copy\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:248:14)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\app10 - Copy\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:294:7)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

android errors

```
    7292-7312/com.example.malli.login2 E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9ac4360
     7292-8793/com.example.malli.login2 E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Are you setting the content type to  "application/json" in your client?

Comment: no i have not done that

Comment: @SelçukCihan can u tell me code for setting content -type

Comment: I need to see the code for your jsonParser object, specifically the makeHttpRequest method; the content type will be set there.

Comment: @SelçukCihan i have added code for header in makeHttpRequest method but after this app is unfortunately getting stopped here is the code  try {if(method == "POST"){ DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);           httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));              httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent()}

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/how-to-send-post-request-in-json-using-httpclient

Comment: @SelçukCihan yes i followed and set the headers but didnot worked

Comment: Could you please add the code snippet to your question, it is difficult to read it like this. You are missing `httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` try to add that too. And for the app stopping, what exception are you getting, post the details please.

Comment: @SelçukCihan i have added a link of image which contains the error that i am getting and added the code of makehttprequest

Comment: That error you posted is the end result. Your `makeHttpRequest` method is returning null and then you are trying to invoke toString() method on it. You have catched the actual exception that is the cause of your problem and you either called `e.printStackTrace` or `Log.e`. We need to see that part to figure out what is going wrong. Could you just remove all the try-catch clauses and then post the error so that we can see the root cause?

Comment: @SelçukCihan i have commented that part of code that was containing json.toString() and  json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS) and removed the try-catch clauses and after doing this i am getting a server error which i have mention in question itself so u can see at there.

Comment: @SelçukCihan and in console i am getting these error  7292-7312/com.example.malli.login2 E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9ac4360                                                            7292-8793/com.example.malli.login2 E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Try using `Map` instead of `List` like `Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);`

Comment: Also, you set `httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");` when you have clearly set `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));` which is `"Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. See the conflict?

Comment: @ElvisChweya i have changed the list to map and i have commented the UrlEncodedFormEntity part and when i have run the app it is hitting the server but i am not getting the data. req.body ,req.params , req.query all were empty

Comment: @SelçukCihan i am getting this error getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9593eb0 in android and in server side it is hitting but  i am not receiving no data

Comment: @SelçukCihan thnks...it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 JSONObject params= new JSONObject();

    try {
        params.put("name", name);     
        params.put("email", email); 
        params.put("password", password);

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);

        httpost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params.toString()));
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        Toast.makeText(this, params.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 

//Other code
```

What is the output of `console.log(req.body);` on the server?

Comment: @user3923278, see the edit...I added `new StringEntity(json.toString());` to post the body as `JSON`. What the output when you log `req.body` serverside?

Comment: now i am getting there errors  Error    in android            converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
/com.example.malli.login2 E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
/com.example.malli.login2 E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9b7fdd0

Comment: Updated to use `JSONObject` instead of `Map`, so multiple data types can be added to a `body`

Comment: output of console.log(req.body); { email: 'qq', name: 'Qq', password: '11' }