# apache httppost how to set content : which have name value pair pointing to another set of name value pair

Tags: java, android, apache, http

For example if we need to send content which is in this format , how do we do it 
{"name1":[{"name11":"value11"},{"name11":"value12"},{"name11":"value13"}],"name2":value2}

I know how to set the basic kind
{"name1":"value1","name2":value2}

```
NameValuePair[] nameValuePairs = new NameValuePair[2];   
            nameValuePairs[0]= new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1");
            nameValuePairs[1] = new BasicNameValuePair("name2", value2);

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

How can we achieve nesting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android) question as it has a couple of answers that should help you. Here is a brief snippet from the answers code:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
    postMessage.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The other answer says you can do something like this:

```
protected void sendJson(final String email, final String pwd) {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                    json.put("email", email);
                    json.put("password", pwd);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "JSON: " + json.toString());  
                    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);
                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }

           }
```

Comment: :) thanks a ton , the first option worked for me .I just create a string in the format i needed - like nested name pair value and used the ByteArrayEntity