# How to send an array of data from Android to php server?

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

For single pair value, I used:

```
datas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude())));
```

Then send it to server using `HttpClient`:

```
HttpClient httpclient = CustomHttpClient.getHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(datas));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
input = entity.getContent();
```

At server side, I extract this information as follows:

```
$latitude = (_POST['latitude']);
```

But for an array of my own type, says `Place` with 3 fields:

```
class Place {
     int id;
     String name;
     String address;
}
```

How can I send this information to my php script? And within my php, how can I extract this JSON array?

Comment: The best way is to use JSON I guess. On php side, use json_decode to retrieve data on the php side. There is plenty of example to send json objects from an Android application.

Answer (score 1):

There are countless methods to transfer data, but one of the more common data-interchange methods is via JSON.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android) for how to do that.  In a nutshell, you

- add JSON support to your "beans," or the elements that you want to transport,
- convert the relevant beans to JSON, and
- send an HTTP request to the remote server, including the JSON data.

See qklxtlx's response for how to interpret the JSON on the server side.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a minimal working example? The link you gave showed how to send data to php server, but the code didn't submit any "key-pair". So at server side, how could I retrieve this JsonArray?

Comment: @Chan Check out the other answer in that link, authored by primpop.

Comment: @Chan Updated answer with your 2nd question.