# passing input parameters to url

Tags: java, httpclient, autologin

I have to pass input parameters to a particular url. I use httpClient to extract the url.
I used Live HttpHeaders to see the input parameters and got this below parameters.

```
{"email":"3rd.ik@gmail.com","password":"etah","meta":{"screen_resolution":{"height":1080,"width":1920}}}
```

Usually I use List and pass the input parameters like this,

```
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "3rd.ik@gmail.com"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passsword", "etah"));   
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("meta",""));
```

But not sure how i will pass the height : width as above. ANy inputs much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but try this `nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("meta[screen_resolution][height]","1080"));`

Comment: nope it didnt help. Thanks anyways.my repsonse.toString gives me '302 Moved temporarily", but doesnt give me the location. "Location: /" is what i get which means i am missing something.

Comment: EDIT your question and paste the output of `live http header`.

Comment: Your input parameter is a valid json. So I think you have to create a json object and than send it. Take a look at [link1](http://localtone.blogspot.in/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android).

Comment: Even JSON would require to add the meta variable. But meta variable has another screen-resolution inside.

Comment: See your content `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` is json.

Comment: Follow the links I mentioned,do some googling. I think you will be able to achieve that.