# android webview working with json post and response

Tags: android, json, webview

I have a sample url like this:

http://www.sample.com/mobile.cgi?action=login&json_request={"user":{"name":"a","pass":"123","gender":"m","age":"25"}}

I can basically use `webview.loadurl` to send data to the server, but the point is...I cant get response from the server. I'm new to json. Is there any way that I can post json using the regular way? like `HttpPost`maybe? and be able to get response properly.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wish to post JSON using `HTTP` and get a response back, there are many posts of stackoverflow which will help you answer that. Check [How to send POST request in JSON using HTTPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218143/android-post-json-using-http) question. I think this question answers what you are trying to say. Hope this helps you. If you have any specific concern you can always comment.

**Update**
As you said that you already have keys and corresponding values in addition to URL.

The first step would be to create a JSON Object. Convert it to string and then you can send it using `HTTPClient` and get the response back. Something like:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/");

try {
    // Add your data

    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    user.put("Name", "a");
    user.put("pass", "123");

    // Create StringEntity
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( user.toString());  
    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

You can check links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389299/post-json-object-on-server-using-httppost) to see further exact format. I wanted to tell you the method as to how you can proceed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: i found many useful answers on StackOverFlow, but the thing is that I don't know how to use them from the url I got. I know name, pass, gender are keys, and a, 123, 25 are values. How can I transform my url to that format? should I include user as the name somewhere? should I include json_request? or the {}??

Comment: long story short...that url above is the only thing I got. I have no clue how to post & get response by just having that url

Comment: Check the updated answer. You can follow the steps. See the added link for more info.

Comment: i tried this code earlier from other posts, but still cant figure out...the 2nd line is already not working bcz eclipse complains that HttpPost doesnt have such constructor.

Comment: Which class are you importing for `HttpPost`? This kind of constructor has been defined for `HttpPost`. See the constructors defined in official [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html#HttpPost%28%29) android document.

Comment: I found several tutorial online regarding how to use json, but still cant figure out how to implement that to my app. In your example, you have "http://www.yoursite.com/" in your HttpPost. but what about in my case? should I put "http://www.sample.com/mobile.cgi?" or "http://www.sample.com/mobile.cgi?action=login&json_request=" ? Also, I tried the example u posted, but got error on this line `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`

Comment: thank you so much for the help. I really can't figure out how to do post and get response by just having that url...

Comment: Why don't you use `HTTP GET`? You should use GET when the interaction is more like a question and your are expecting a response. See [Here](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html). It allows you to use parameters within the `HttpGet` request string. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2959431/1306419). If you want to do a post with parameters see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) thread.

Comment: I found someone had the exact same question from your link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android/2959431#2959431)

Comment: @Yog Guru was asking the same thing, but no one answered. I found another way to make it work without getting response from json! thanks for all the help

Comment: Great to hear that you got it working.What did you do? #Just Curious