# How i write in json file on server

Tags: android, json, networking

i have JSON FILE on my localhost i
 want to update it via code how i do that any help plz ?
i have list.JSON ON MY LOCAL 
HOST  i want delete all data in it and 
write new data in it 
and update it on server ?

```
can any one tell me how i do that ?
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////
   ///////////////////////////
         ////////////////////
```

Comment: Why is this "///////////////////////////////////////////////" ?

Comment: donot care about it this cuz topic so short so i can not add it

Comment: @DheereshSingh It's a line that's commented very well.

Comment: you want to update the json of server from phone ?

Comment: i have JSON file on server i want update data in this file

Comment: yes but I am confirming you to update that from phone (as per data taken by user on phone)..?

Comment: i work on emulator of eclipse

Comment: yes i get new data from user on phone

Answer (score 1):

[How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

```
 1- crate a page on server which takes this json and update it and take it's url 


2- take the input from user 
3- put it in a bean/model (wrap in object form as per structure )
4- crate the json from object (can use libraries like GSON for this
5- use post method to push json to srver
```