# 406 Error for the Post JSON data to webserver in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am working for the crate application for the  **drupal** based website.Here I face the problem for the post page from application to web server.

When I post the title and body then only title is appeared on server but body is not appeaerd.Here my body part into **`json`** format.

Below JSON format works perfectly into poster plugin of firefox,it successfully writes data to server, so now my question is to write android code for the same task.

```
{
 "type":"page",
 "title":"TITLE TESTING",
 "body":{
   "und":[
   {
    "value":"BODY TESTING"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I have tried like this:

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type","page"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title",title));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", ""+jSONCategory.toString()));
 //  value of the jSONCategory.toString() : {"und":[{"value":"body_part"}]}

System.out.println("============@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+params);
```

when I print the value of the params then t display me like :

```
[type=page, title=title_part, body={"und":{"value":"body_part","format":"full_html"}]}]
```

And when I pass only the body part then it gives me **status code 406** and for title it works perfect with **200 status code**

Here my questions is how to pass **string + json** both combine to server.
Here title part is `String variable` and body part is json variable`enter code here`

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
  JSONCategory = new JSONObject();
  JSONBody = new JSONObject();

 JSONObject Jsonvalue = new JSONObject();
                    Jsonvalue.put("value", body);

                    JSONArray jsonUnd = new JSONArray(); 
                    jsonUnd.put(Jsonvalue);

                    JSONCategory.put("und", jsonUnd);

                    JSONBody.put("type", "page");
                    JSONBody.put("title", title);
                    JSONBody.put("body", JSONCategory);

                    System.out
                            .println("WHOLE JSON OBJECT ====================>"
                                    + JSONBody.toString());
```

Logcat :

```
 WHOLE JSON OBJECT ====================>{"type":"page","body":{"und":[{"value":"body"}]},"title":"title"}
```

JAVA code

```
@Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "url here";

        // strResponse1= postData(url,title,JSONCategory);
        postData(url, JSONBody);

        System.out.println("=========> Response from post  idea => "
                + strResponse1);

        return null;
    }
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     protected void  postData(final String url, final JSONObject mainJSON) {


            Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                    HttpResponse response;

                    try{
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(mainJSON.toString());  
                        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        post.setEntity(se);
                        response = client.execute(post);
                        /*Checking response */
                        if(response!=null){
                            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        }

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                    }
                    Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
                }
            };
            t.start();      


 }
```

Comment: [Linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Comment: 4** errors usually mean that your application f**ked up and sent something server does not like -  answer may be in offended  server logs

Comment: i have same issues am posting json string and concerting to json object  it having 20 fields,am getting 406 status code...... how to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built in JSON API's instead of Lists. In your case, traversing from innermost object to the outermost object, it would look like this:

```
JSONObject j4=new JSONObject(); 
j4.put("value",test_value); 

JSONArray j3=new JSONArray(); 
j3.put(0,j4); 

JSONObject j2=new JSONObject(); 
j2.put("und",j3);

JSONObject j1=new JSONObject(); 
j1.put("type","page");
j1.put("title",title_string); 
j1.put("body",j2);
```

Then, `j1.toString();` would give you your required json string for output.

Then you can use a standard HTTP POST to send it to the server (using threads to keep network code off your UI thread) like this:

```
protected void sendJson(JSONObject j1) {
        Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;

                try{
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( j1.toString());  
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);
                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }
                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };
        t.start();      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have already done this,I got this values into `jSONCategory`, but my prblem how to pass this values to the server.

Comment: what was the error? print out j1.toString() and see if the string output is proper or not first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17643/discussion-between-anup-cowkur-and-rahul-patel)