# How JSON can be used and implemented in .net?

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

Can anyone help me out how to use JSON in ASP.Net? I am unaware of AJAX and JQuery. I am just a beginner. (Whether it can be implemented both in ASP.Net and Console Application?)

Comment: try a tutorial first and search on google.

Comment: refer this [How to use JSON in .Net][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447608/display-image-using-json/13447855#13447855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("(link for fetching json data)");
    myReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    myReq.Accept = "apllication/json";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
    string myString= response.GetResponseHeader("Registration_Status");
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        json = sr.ReadToEnd();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\others\DemoCreatingCustomEvents\TextFile1.txt");
        sw.Write(label1.Content.ToString());
        sw.Close();
    }
}

string json="";

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    ProductCategory deserializedProdCategory = new ProductCategory();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedProdCategory.GetType());

    deserializedProdCategory = ser.ReadObject(ms) as ProductCategory;
    ms.Close();


//you can fetch the data here and it is shown in label
        label1.Content = deserializedProdCategory.ProdCategory[1].Product_ID + "//" + deserializedProdCategory.ProdCategory[1].Product_Name;
    }
    public class ProductCategory
    {
        public List<Product> ProdCategory = new List<Product>();
        public ProductCategory()
        {
            ProdCategory = new List<Product>();
        }
    }


    public class Product
    {
        public int Product_ID { get; set; }
        public string Product_Code { get; set; }
        public string Product_Name { get; set; }
        public Uri Image_Small { get; set; }
    }
```