# How to send JSON object over request to web service in android

Tags: android

I would like to pass JSON object as request to web service like i mentioned below.

```
Result:{
 "email":"xxxxxxx",
 "password":"xxxxxx",
 "Marks":[
  {
   "mark1":"50",
   "mark2":"70"
  }
],
"firstname":"xxxx",
"lastname":"xxxxx"
}
```

My code:
...

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("My Url");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(**message**.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Here **message** should have json object in above format.How could i format JSON object?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you arer having trouble in implementing above json object at android side then you can construct it like below,

```
JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

JSONObject mParams = new JSONObject();
mParams.put("email", "xxxx");
mParams.put("password", "xxx");

JSONArray markArray = new JSONArray(); 
JSONObject markObj = new JSONObject();
markObj.put("mark1", "50");
markObj.put("mark2", "70");
markArray.put(markObj);

mParams.put("Marks", markArray);

mParams.put("FirstName", "xxxx");
mParams.put("lastname", "xxxx");

message.put("Result",mParams);
```

Now in your code

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("My Url");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(**message**.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: If i use ur code i got unserialized output like {"Result":{"lastname":"xxxx","FirstName":"xxxx","Marks":[{"mark2":"70","mark1":"50"}],"password":"xxx","email":"xxxx"}}

Comment: the position of fields are changed.i need to have email,pass,marks,firstname,lastname in this order.And i dont need the open& close bracket before Result & end

Comment: Order doesn't matter for the JSON - This by default due to its design structure. Your server side code will detect it properly as it will evaluate it based on the Key-value pair.

Comment: My output was considering "Result" as a key that's why it was formatted as a perfect json object. You can verify Json by using jsonlint.com. If json is not in valid format then server side code will not detect it as a json object and will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can just send it like a String:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", message.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

and

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the JSON which you have mentioned above is **INVALID**.

Now,

> Here message should have json object in above format.How could i
>   format JSON object?

=> There are 2 ways to do that:

**1) Create a request structure by using JSONObject or JSONArray classes, something like:**

JSONObject objRequest = new JSONObject();
objRequest.putString("email","xxxx");
objRequest.putString("password","xxxx");

while setting entity inside HttpPost object, convert it into the String value.

**2) Bad way, simple generate a string value with escape sequences, something like:**

```
String strRequest = "{\"email\":\"xxxxxxx\",\"password\":\"xxxxxx\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..Use GSON library. GSON is a Google library to parse JSON resources. With regards to the Marshalling, it basically means a way to translate data structures (like objects in an OOP language) to JSON... [for instance](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonmarshaller-java-15-marshalling):

```
// Java object
class Book {
  private String title;
  private String isbn;
  private Set<author> authors;
}

@Entity
class Author {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

To...

```
{title:   "Vocation Createurs",
 isbn:    "2829302680",
 authors: [{firstName: "Barbara", lastName: "Polla"},
           {firstName: "Pascal",  lastName: "Perez"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use existing libraries like android-json-rpc