# how to post data in JSON from android?

Tags: android, json

IN JSON Parsing in Android as i wants to post the data with below format on http URL,

```
 webdata={"email":"test@test.com","password":"123456"}
```

how can i post this data by the use of httppost for this JSON on http url ?

Comment: You want to post the total json string or just email and password?

Comment: Try this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android

Answer (score 1):

First you can prepare your json format data then send that as your request as per your requirement either GET or  POST this need to be done with using Asynctask

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
try{
jObject.put("email",urvalue);
jObject.put("password",urvalue);

List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("webdata", jObject.toString()));

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following method for generating json Object

```
private JSONObject getConvertedinJson(String email, String password) {

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("email", email);
        object.put("password", password);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

after that use following method for posting json object on url

```
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, JSONObject jObj) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Default Http Client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Http Post Header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // Execute Http Post Request
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
     * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
     * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
     * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
     */
    try {
        // Getting Server Response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        // Reading Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    Log.e("JSON Parser", jObj.toString());
    return jObj;

}
```

Now Use following statement to get json response.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = getJSONFromUrl(
                "www.url.com/api",
                getConvertedinJson("test@test.com",
                        "123456"));
```

Now you can easily Deserialize jsonObject according to need.

**Note: Your Post Data must be Json Object. As I have seen webdata={"email":"test@test.com","password":"123456"}  is not jsonObject here json Object is only {"email":"test@test.com","password":"123456"}**

Answer (score 0):

use `StringEntity` class.

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("Your JSON String",HTTP.UTF_8);
```

and then add it to your `HttpPost`

```
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```