# how to send on the server variables float?

Tags: android, http-post

I need `{"location":{"lat": 50.4, "lng": 30.5}}`  send on the server

i do this

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
List<NameValuePair> gps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            gps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", Util
                    .getLatitude()));
            gps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", Util
                    .getLatitude()));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location",gps.toString()));
```

`{"location":{"lat": "50.4", "lng": "30.5"}}`

**I need to send the type of float not string**

Comment: why don't you just cast it on the server side from string to float?

Comment: because the customer wants, I have to understand I can send float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send json Obejct to sever then first create it using `JSONObject` instead of  passing jsonobejct's values using `NameValuePair` . create current JSONObject as :

```
// main jsonObject
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
// location JSONObject
JSONObject jsonlocation = new JSONObject();

// put key-value in  jsonlocation JSONObject
jsonlocation.put("lat", Util.getLatitude());  //<< put lat
jsonlocation.put("lng", Util.getLatitude());  //<< put lng

// put jsonlocation in main json JSONObject

json.put("location",jsonlocation);
```

now send `json` object to sever.

for sending JSONObject to server see

[How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to send JSON to the server? Your code gps.toString() creates a string value of your List, not JSON. You should use a JSON library (GSON for example), to parse your List to valid JSON.

With GSON, you can parse your list to JSON like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(list);
```