# update a listview automatically : Android

Tags: android, mysql

How can I update my ListView automatically when I update my mysql database ? for example: "when I receive a new mail, Gmail app updates the mails ListView automatically !"

Comment: You need to use ContentObserver class for your database, then use update adapter which updates listview. Please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

Comment: Look into this interface LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>

Answer (score 0):

Call this when ever you add or remove data from the database:

```
YourListView.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: I should make things more clear : When the database is updated ! all the clients should receive a notification and get their listview updated automatically (like chat apps : whatsapp ..etc)

Comment: I'm guessing the database isn't stored locally?
Do you have a function where you check if there is any changes in the database, or is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: I have a shared mysql database ! I add/update data using webservice (php files stored in server )

Comment: Well, you have to have some function that checks the database.
Unless you want to have the server notify all the users.

Comment: Ok! I can send a notification using JSON to clients whenever one of them add/update data, but my question is : how to receive this notification? Can I use Broadcast receiver ?

Comment: This is really not my field. But I can suggest this:
Create a JSON function that calls the server every 15min or what ever, and the response should give you a the size of a given table or something that you can use to compare the last check with.
This link might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android

Comment: I found the solution : Google Cloud Messaging  http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html