# How to call API with Body Content

Tags: android, api

I have tried to get post response like

```
StringEntity  entity;
private static final int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 20000;
private static final String serverurl = "http://appcodetechnology.net/meravenue/api/";
```

below function m calling

```
  post("master_details.php");
```

//

```
public String post(String request)
    {
        String result = null;
        try
        {   
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            System.out.println("Getting url: "+request);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverurl+request);

             String body  = "{\"action\":\"get_all_cities\"}";

                try {
                    //entity = new StringEntity("action=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(body, "utf-8"));                     
                    //entity = new StringEntity("data=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(body, "utf-8"));                       
                     entity = new StringEntity(java.net.URLEncoder.encode(body, "utf-8"));                          
                     entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
               // entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                post.setEntity(entity);


            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null)
            {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Response Failed","Response from server is failed");
            }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and response getting

```
{"result":false,"message":"Invalid method name.","error_code":"406"}
```

no any error i m getting.

for below API i m working

```
URL : http://appcodetechnology.net/meravenue/api/master_details.php
Method : POST
Request Body : {"action":"get_all_cities"}
```

but not getting response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to post a json object:

```
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("YOUR_KEY", YOUR_VALUE);
                post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json .toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
```

Or just ref this page to find how to post json:

[How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Comment: not getting reponse ,  String body  = "\"action\":\"get_all_cities\""; managing issue

Comment: what error do you get? what do you mean by "String body = "\"action\":\"get_all_cities\""; managing issue"?

Comment: i have tried according your example, no error getting , respone like = {"result":false,"message":"Invalid method name.","error_code":"406"} this i m geting

Comment: body should be {"action":"get_all_cities"}

Comment: in Numvalues is passing like  action=get_all_cities

Comment: oh, i see. you should make your body to be "{\"action\":\"get_all_cities\"}"; the service need to decode from your json string. see my edit

Comment: i run curl in my linux console, got this:[root@192.168.0.197 ~]# curl --data "{\"action\":\"get_all_cities\"}" http://appcodetechnology.net/meravenue/api/master_details.php
{"get_all_cities":[{"city_id":"1","state_id":"23","city_name":.......

Comment: yet not getting respone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35504/discussion-between-ankit-makwana-and-kevinhoo)

Comment: request ? whose object

Comment: did you fix the problem?