# send other parameters and complex json object to server android

Tags: android, httpresponse, json

I want to perform following task :

1 > accept input from user and save it

2 > Send this input value with whole json object to server

[This is log cat result](http://pastie.org/8574104)

Answer (score 0):

see this

http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

[How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android/3027900#3027900)

Comment: i want to send request to Server eg Flight search on particular time duration and place and get that record in listview

Answer (score 0):

USe The following code..

```
        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
        jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```