# How to convert strings in json and pass to webservice in android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am working on web services in android,
i have three strings

```
String username = "Rajesh";
String password = "abc"
String usertype = "member";
```

and i want to send them to web service in the following form

```
 {"UserName":username,"Password":password,"UserType":usertype}
```

like

```
 {"UserName":"Rajesh","Password":"abc","UserType":"member"}
```

web service url is something like : http://abc.xyz.org/api/login

i dont have any idea how to do it, please help me,
how can i convert strings to json like above and how can i pass it to web service
Thank you

Comment: it's a json object. Its creation is trivial

Comment: I dont have idea about it, can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, `JSONObject.put()` uses a key value pair so do as needed:

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("username", "rajesh");
    object.put("password", "password");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After forming the required `JSONObject` you can use `HttpClient` to send it onto a request, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027900/2247689).

You can also refer to my project on making `Http` requests on android [here](https://github.com/rakeeb11/google-api-interaction).

Comment: Ok Thank you for this and then how can i pass it to web service? can you please give me the full code for that ?

Comment: I've also shared a project with you. @RajeshSuthar

Comment: please vote up if you thing my question can be useful to others

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use by Json Object Like below,

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("UserName", "Rajesh"); 
jsonObj.put("Password", "abc");
jsonObj.put("UserType", "member");
```

If you send In webservice then

```
String json = jsonObj.toString();

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

also check [pass json object in url](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/)

Comment: Ok Thank you for this and then how can i pass it to web service? can you please give me the full code for that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.aven.qqdemo;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonUutis {

private void toWebService(){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    String username = "Rajesh";
    String password = "abc";
    String usertype = "member";
    putJson(json,"UserName", username);
    putJson(json,"Password", password);
    putJson(json,"UserType", usertype);
    String jsonString = json.toString();
    //Send jsonString to web service.
}

private void putJson(JSONObject json, String key, String value){
    try {
        json.put(key, value);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Error happened.
    }
}
```

}