# how to send large string to server in android?

Tags: php, android, http-post

i want to send large string to server from android, i can send small string with this methos

```
        InputStream is;
        String name = "Name";
        String str = "LargeString";

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("encoded", str));

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new
            HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/test/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = (InputStream) entity.getContent();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

        }
```

With this code i able to send small string but can't large string.
Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: in post u can send large strings, any erros u getting?

Comment: what is the error, show the logcat info

Comment: this link will help you [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?] 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android

Comment: no error it show but when i send small string it work but with large string not work

Comment: i trying to send video encoded string

Comment: @Rajneesh Make sure your server setting allows you to upload large file. For example, suppose you are using wamp server..then there is possibility that Max limit for file upload is set to a lesser number. [http://blog.bytedevelopers.com/increase-import-size-wamp-phpmyadmin/]

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

You can take reference from [here](http://ihofmann.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/android-sending-post-requests-with-parameters/).