# How to send json to http url connection android

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I have HTTP path that need to send JSON

```
{
    "domain": "mas.org.il",
    "params": {
        "type":"hug"
    }
}
```

to get another JSON with all items to insert into my Android app

How do I send this JSON to http URL and get JSON to parse it into my app.

Comment: why not turn the json object into a string and send it to URL then convert back to JSON in script? you can implement the volley library in your android app. in the script when you are done processing you can echo back the response in json format

Answer (score 0):

please read this useful document to know how can you implementing this feature

https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a vary basic idea,add the json in apache NameValue pair or use apache Entitys with HttpPost .. or you can follow this.

[How To Send json Object to the server from my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390928/how-to-send-json-object-to-the-server-from-my-android-app)