# Android send json to Spring

Tags: java, android, json, ajax, spring

Spring Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public int checkLoginInfo(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
     User user=new Gson().fromJson((String) params.get("user"), User.class);
     return userService.getUserInfo(user);
 }
```

HTML

```
var params={userid:$("#userid").val(),password:$("#password").val()}
$ajax({method:"post",data:{user:JSON.stringify(params)},url:"foo.bar"});
```

It worked on website.
But I don't know how to send that Json object for android.

```
data:{user:JSON.stringify(params)}
```

I have tested

```
    private static String makeJsonMsg() {
    String retMsg = "";

    JSONStringer jsonStringer = new JSONStringer();

    try {


        retMsg = jsonStringer.object()
                    .key("user").object()
                        .key("userid").value("userid")
                        .key("password").value("1234")
                    .endObject()
                .endObject().toString();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retMsg;

}
```

like that,
But return 500 error.
Do I need to add header or something else?

Comment: Error 500 means that there was a server-side problem. You'll need to include the exception stack trace, the code without it isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way, taken from [@Sachin Gurnani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390152/4848308) to [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

> ```java
> public void postData(String url,JSONObject obj) {
>     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
>
>     HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
>     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
>     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
>     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams );
>     String json=obj.toString();
>
>     try {
>
>         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
>         httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
>
>         StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString()); 
>         se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/> json"));
>         httppost.setEntity(se); 
>
>         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
>         String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
>         Log.i("tag", temp);
>
>
>     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>     }
> }
> ```

How to use

```
JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
requestObject.put("userid", email);
requestObject.put("password", password);

postData("http://your/login/url",requestObject)
```