# Sending json object via http post method in android

Tags: android, json, http-post, httprequest, httpurlconnection

> its NOT DUPLICATE.Link that has been provided is an OLD one."http client" has been removed in api23

I want to send json object:

```
{"emailId":"ashish.bhatt@mobimedia.in","address":"Naya bans","city":"Noida","pincode":"201301","account_number":"91123546374208","bank_name":"Axis Bank","branch_name":"91123546374208","ifsc_code":"UTI0000879"}
```

to url:

> http://10digimr.mobimedia.in/api/mobile_retailer/update_profile
>   How do i do it?
>   via post method?

METHOD:

```
 POST /api/mobile_retailer/update_profile
```

MANDATORY KEY:

```
{"emailId","address"}
```

REQUEST JSON:

```
{"emailId":"ashish.bhatt@mobimedia.in","address":"Naya bans","city":"Noida","pincode":"201301","account_number":"91123546374208","bank_name":"Axis Bank","branch_name":"91123546374208","ifsc_code":"UTI0000879"}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{"message":"Mail Send","data":true,"status":200}
```

Comment: the api you have mentioned is a GET method. Ask the API developer for documentation about the correct way to access the API. I tried sending a POSt request to it via rest client. It gives an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Comment: my bad! wrong url was written!

Comment: its NOT DUPLICATE.Link that has been provided is an OLD one."http client" has been removed in api23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a class `AsyncT` and call it in `onCreate` method using:

```
AsyncT asyncT = new AsyncT();
asyncT.execute();
```

Class definition:

```
class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(""); //Enter URL here
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // here you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("para_1", "arg_1");

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: @gothdo How do you handle the response that you get from the post message ?

Answer (score 0):

@Sandip Subedi This is how you get response from the httpURLConnection

```
class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(""); //Enter URL here
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // here you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("para_1", "arg_1");

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                InputStream response = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                       is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
```