# Sending HTTP POST request in java (android studio)

Tags: java, android

Yes, there are many questions out there like this. Most are old, and bring up compile errors in android studio though.

I want to make a simple post request, and send json encoded data. I am a complete java n00b, so please bear with me. Currently taking from this question: [Sending json object via http post method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833798/sending-json-object-via-http-post-method-in-android)

Here is what I have now:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://myURL.com"); 
        String type = "application/json";
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", type); 
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("myKey", "myValue");

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am calling this method in onCreate in my MainActivity.java file. It compiles with no errors, but when I run it, it crashes and I see the "your app has stopped" alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: logcat error details ?

Comment: did you add the internet permission in manifest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application

Comment: @nandsito my manifest has:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> is that what you mean? if so then yes it was already added

Comment: `calling this method in onCreate`? I dont see a method/function. Only some code. Please be exact.

Comment: @greenapps in my project, the code I posted is inside a function. the function is called in onCreate

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I see only: Connected to process 11053 on device emulator-5554
Application terminated.

Comment: You should look in the logcat. There you will see the reason of the crash. I bet you have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: As i already thought. You cannot call such a function in onCreate.