# how can post this json to php file from android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to send a list of selected items with count by `AsyncTask`

```
 data:{ 
 id : 1
 tokend : xxxx
 objects :{ 0:{id:1,count:4} , 1:{id:3,count:2} }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android)

Comment: @BertrandMartel In this case, we have two Json inside that have internal keys equal